# Websites projects on different drive to WAMP install result in forbidden 403

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7

I have installed WAMP to `C:/wamp/...` and I would like to have my projects on my second drive, d. I have the following in my vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin postmaster@example.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/websites/example/public_html"
  ServerName example.local
  ServerAlias www.example.local
  ErrorLog "logs/example.local-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/example.local-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and added `example.local` to my hosts file. However the project produces a 403 Forbidden error. Projects inside the default `wamp/www/` directory work. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <Directory "d:/yourpath">
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
```

add that within the VirtualHost tag.